# Storyboard could not be found in release build

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, app-store

I've the problem that my *Debug* and *Ad-Hoc* builds are working fine. Only the *AppStore* build doesn't work and that's why it got rejected. If I extract the ipa file from the archive (which I used for the app store release) the app crashes on launch. The ips log file Apple provided clearly states

> Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard_iPhone' in bundle NSBundle xxx

On my on environment the following symbolicated log file is generated

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xfffffffc
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2c8355f2 __exceptionPreprocess + 122
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a0a7c72 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   UIKit                           0x3022d2f8 +[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:] + 680
```

So the problem is the loading of the storyboard. In my case I needed access to the used storyboard instance. Therefore I set the **Main Interface** to empty for both iPhone and iPad in *Build > iOS Application*. Instead I use the following code in my app delegate:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone) {
    Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("MainStoryboard_iPhone", null);
} else {
    Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("MainStoryboard_iPad", null);
}
```

In the app delegate I have a variable which can be later accessed anywhere in the project through `AppDelegate.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("xxx")`.

I think the problem lies in that approach. But how can I access the current loaded storyboard when I set the storyboards in the **Main Interface**?

First I thought this is similar to [Migrating from Classic to Unified API breaks my project](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30860/migrating-from-classic-to-unified-api-breaks-my-project), but I have these settings:

```
<!-- TODO: check for duplicate items -->
<Target Name="_CopyContentToBundle" DependsOnTargets="_CollectBundleResources;_GenerateBundleName"
    Inputs = "@(_BundleResourceWithLogicalName)"
    Outputs = "@(_BundleResourceWithLogicalName -> '$(_AppBundlePath)%(LogicalName)')" >
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that doing a **clean build** was needed. I've done the following:

- Build > Clean all
- Build > Clean AppName
- Delete bin and obj folder
- Build > Create new AppName

and then the rest (creating archive, validating archive, submitting to the app store). Hopefully it does now work.

This is how I tried to reproduce this issue:

Export an ipa-file from Xcode's Organizer (Save for Ad Hoc Deployment). Dropped the ipa-file into iTunes when the device is not connected! Then connect the device, install and apply the changes.

**Remark for myself**:

Test AppStore releases before submitting to App Store.